# What is the relation between electromotive force and energy stored in a cell which can be converted to other energy in the external circuit?

Tags: energy, electric-circuits, potential, voltage, batteries

We usually define electromotive force of a cell as the energy stored in the cell(atleast I have noticed it to be defined like that). But isn't electromotive force equivalent to electric potential since their units are **Volts**? Moreover isn't electromotive force defined as the amount of energy required to move a 1C charge from one point of the circuit to the same point traversing the whole circuit including the cell itself? So what is the relation between e.m.f and total energy(that is convertible) stored in a cell?

Does e.m.f mean that each group of electrons having net charge 1C released from that cell possess energy equivalent to the e.m.f? If that is so then based on the resistance of the external circuit, amount of current flow changes. So what happens then? I mean if current changes how do we evaluate the amount of energy stored in the cell or the energy that is converted in the external circuit?

I want to know the direct relation between e.m.f and energy(that is in **Joules** unit)

Comment: Wheeen I were in school, for batteries, it meant "It is the battery's voltage, but you are now responsible for taking the battery's resistance into consideration".

Answer (score 1):

The term Electromotive force is very misleading and I'll stick with the abbreviation EMF.

EMF is not a force. It's a potential difference between the two terminals of the Voltage source. To be more precise, it's the energy U required to take a unit positive charge from negative terminal of the battery to its positive terminal overcoming both the attractive and repulsive forces of the terminals. For any other magnitude of charge, the energy required is the product of this energy U and the charge. So, potential is defined as energy per unit charge.

Whenever you have a charge separation( + & -) at a distance, you have a potential difference or a rather potential energy, because there is a force between these charges that attracts them and we use some other mechanical force to separate them. So if this force is missing, their potential to be together becomes certain and they will gain velocity which converts their potential energy into kinetic energy. In general we have potentials as potential energy stored per unit charge.

The battery is a device that converts it's chemical energy to potential energy by creating a charge separation at its terminals. The terminals therefore possess opposite charges which creates a potential difference or voltage= EMF of the cell. This EMF itself has the units of Voltage that is Joules/Coulomb.

I understand how the terminology might have confused you. It's a disaster if you think of EMF as a force. It's a serious issue that we are just stuck with. That's why in most textbooks, EMF is not expanded more that once or add a disclaimer to it.

Comment: I am not thinking it as force but even by considering it as energy I am still confused.